# Как узнать пуст ли обьект - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты, if

Как мне определить пуст ли обьект? При пустом обьекте я получаю [] ,но если я проверяю пуст ли обьект пишет undefined.

Когда я проверяю обьект который имеет значения, то получаю эти самые значения, но когда я проверяю пустой обьект, получаю undefined.

Так в чем сам вопрос, как мне через if узнать о пустоте обьекта?
Ниже написаный код НЕ работает:

```js
    let user = {
      name: "John",
      age: 30
    };
    let usernull = {};
    if(user !== undefined) { 
     console.log(user.name);
    } else { 
     console.log("true");
    }; // Получаю John
   
    if(usernull !== {} || usernull !== undefined) {
    console.log(usernull)
} else {
console.log("truenull");
} // Получаю {}, а должен truenull
```

Помогите исправить пожалуйста.

P.S Заранее извиняюсь если неконкретно сформировал вопрос

Comment: `usernull !== {} || usernull !== undefined` такое условие всегда `true`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно проверить вот так

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30
};
let usernull = {};

console.log( Object.keys(user).length, Object.keys(usernull).length );
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте:

```
//user - обьект для проверки
if(Object.keys(user).length === 0 && user.constructor === Object){
   // Код здесь...
}
```

Так же реализации в библиотеках:

[JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/):

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject({}); // true
```

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#isEmpty):

```
_.isEmpty(null); // true
```

[Underscore:](https://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty)

```
_.isEmpty({}); // true
```